# HTML input not updating on paste

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to capture the value of whatever is pasted into a text input, but it's not showing up in the text input for some reason

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {

  handleOnPaste = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const pastedData = clipboardData.getData("Text");

    console.log(pastedData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onPaste={e => this.handleOnPaste(e)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working, just declare the function in a proper way like,

```js
  const handleOnPaste = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const pastedData = clipboardData.getData("Text");

    console.log(pastedData);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I. declare your function with `const`

```
    const handleOnPaste = e => {
       // Implementation
    }
```

II. pass your function without `this` because this is a function component, not a class component.

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onPaste={e => handleOnPaste(e)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

You can also pass your function like:

```
onPaste={handleOnPaste}
```

Comment: Did this but the text input is still blank on paste

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you are mixing class based component's concepts in functional component. So use `const` to define handlers and don't use this.

See [Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-paste-issue-fix-joobd?file=/src/App.js).

FYI - You can also use `navigator.clipboard`

**Code snippet**

```js
export default function App() {
  const handleOnPaste = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //  First way
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const pastedData = clipboardData.getData("Text");
    console.log(pastedData);
    // Another way -- navigator.clipboard
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(copiedText => console.log('copiedText', copiedText));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onPaste={handleOnPaste}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `e.preventDefault()` is what's stopping the input from updating. It's unnecessary if you're happy for the field to update